# How can I best create a second (variant) Anki deck from an existing deck

Tags: anki

I have a set of language learning cards, English on the front, French on the back. I'd like to create (as deck that can be independently studied and shared) a set of cards that are almost, *but not quite*, a reversal of the existing cards/deck. More specifically, I would like the French sentence on the front and the English on the back, but I would prefer not to show some of the other fields at all and to change the information in some of the note fields.
I am only an Anki novice so the following information might not be useful: ... when I look at the deck in the browser, I can see that the card-field of ever note is labelled "Card 1".

How might I best go about achieving my goal?